# How to get Collections name from Cosmos DB using Mongo API

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

- I am trying to execute Mongo API to perform CRUD operation on Azure Cosmos-DB.

  - I am running the query on Azure Data explorer.
  - This is a query that I am executing `{db.getCollectionNames()}`

[image: Here]

- I am facing `{"code":500,"body":"{\"message\":\"There was an error processing your request. Please try again in a few moments.\",\"httpStatusCode\":\"InternalServerError\",\"xMsServerRequestId\":null,\"stackTrace\":null}"}`

Can you please suggest the changes if I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `Mongo Query` area is not the same as a native MongoDB shell. That is, the only thing you can do within the query window is execute `find()` queries, and you only specify the filtering (between the `{}`). For example:

[image: screenshot of running mongo query in browser]

There's also the ability to open a mongo shell via the browser, where you can run queries, in the more traditional format for mongo:

[image: mongo shell launch menu]

[image: mongo shell]

With the browser-based shell, you can also do updates (e.g. `db.families.update()`) and deletes (`db.families.remove()`). But it doesn't support commands such as `db.getCollectionNames()`.

Comment: Thanks For the answer. When I try for new MongoShell I am getting `ERROR: Failed to create resources on DB on server`

Comment: Not sure what you did to get that error. Just opening the shell? Typing something into the shell? I can't tell, from your comment.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. Now I am getting another error I update my question

Comment: Please do *not* do that. Ask a new question. I answered your question and got you past the issue (and you even accepted the answer). By changing the entire question, you effectively invalidated my answer. **Note** - I rolled back your edit, to keep this question+answer valid.